# How should I avoid repeated evaluation of lots of bashrc commands in shells-within-shell-sessions?

Tags: bash, shell-script

In bash, we have the inherent separation of `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`, with the former running for login shells and the other for all shells. Now, I [understand](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272491/why-is-setting-alias-in-profile-not-working/828105#828105) it's common to start an interactive non-login shell from a non-shell process, and for this reason I find myself running quite a bit of initialization stuff in my `.bashrc`. The thing is, one also often invokes the shell from within an interactive shell session, or within shell scripts; and I'm not at all sure none of them runs `.bashrc`. So, I think I would like to somehow constrain some of the stuff I do in my `.bashrc` to only happen in "top-level" interactive shells in some sense.

Is there some convention on how this is done? Or perhaps, is it too much of a hassle compared to the benefit?

Comment: Subshells don't run `.bashrc`. They don't really need to, since they're already copies of the main shell which already did run whatever initialization files it did in the mode it was in. That should be easy to check by putting something like `echo this is bashrc` in `.bashrc` and running e.g. `(echo hi)` or `: $(echo hi)`.

Comment: I suppose by "subshell" he means new `bash` process...(for the record, when run as `sh`, `--norc` is implied...)

Comment: @TomYan, perhaps. And the possible misuse of the word is why I didn't write that as an answer. But the question doesn't _show_ what they mean.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you mean by subshell. Neither subshells nor shell scripts read bashrc normally so this is all a bit unclear. Can you maybe add some specific examples?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like what you want to do is to avoid .bashrc from being (fully) sourced again if the new bash process is spawned from one that already did, regardless of whether it's interactive or not.

You can do something like this:

```
Hello, I am a "first" shell
$ cat .bashrc
[ -n "$SPAWNING" ] && return

export SPAWNING=yes

echo 'Hello, I am a "first" shell'
$ bash
$
exit
$ env -i bash
Hello, I am a "first" shell
$ exit
$
```

As I've shown though, there's still the caveat that it won't help when the new bash is spawned with all the env var cleared.

Comment: That sounds reasonable. And - if someone clears the environment than it's their responsibility anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The "$-" variable contains the options for the current shell at its invocation; you might find "i" present, which would indicate an interactive shell.

```
case "$-" in
*i*) echo in interactive shell
     # do interactive-only setup here
     ;;
esac
```

Comment: though AFAIK `bashrc` is only read by interactive shells, and if it's sourced from the "profile" files for login shells, it's often guarded by the check on `$-` or `$PS1` anyway. (`PS1` also being unset in non-interactive shells.)

Comment: I think bash's command-line is such that it reads bashrc and bash_profile unless you tell it not to, regardless of interactivity. Am I wrong? Also, is a shell called from within an interactive shell not interactive itself?

Comment: @einpoklum, no, it doesn't always read them, see: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html#Bash-Startup-Files. Though the rules there are somewhat complex, but mainly it reads "profile" for interactive login shells and "bashrc" for interactive non-login shells. Yes, if you run `bash` from an interactive shell, opening a new shell you can interact with, that's another interactive shell. But _it's not a subshell_, which is why people keep asking you to edit your question to show what situation you actually mean.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Edited.